# missing animation in R.anim and Progressbar in ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, android-widget

I like to get the two slide in animation, 
which are missing I think. how can I do this, 
anything would be very nice

```
android.R.anim.slide_in_right
android.R.anim.slide_out_left
```

I would liek to slide in some pictures the other way around is working

on the other side, is it possible to have an progress bar under the picture which shows how much pictures are left

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All system resources are located in the SDK folder.

Grab the animations you want from

> SDK_folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\anim

and place them in your project under `res/anim`

Then you can use them with

```
R.anim.anim_name
```

Comment: thank you, this helps me. is it possible to have a progress bar under the imageswitcher which shows how much slides are left to each side ?